# Accessing VTABLE directily issues undefined error

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, vtable

I was experimenting with virtual table and virtual pointer. To know more I did the following:

```
  //a simple class
  class X
  {
  public:
       // fn is a simple virtual function
       virtual void fn() { cout << "n = " << n << endl; }
       // a member variable
       int n;
  };

  int main()
  {
     // create an object (obj) of class X
     X *obj = new X();
     obj->n = 10;

     // get the virtual table pointer of object obj
     int* vptr =  *(int**)obj;

     __asm__("mov %eax, obj;");

     // function fn is the first entry of the virtual table, so it's vptr[0]
     ((void (*)()) vptr[0])();

     // the above should be the same as the following
     //obj->fn();

     return 0;
  }
```

But compiler is giving the following error:

> /home/OaVTND/cclnoQaK.o: In function 'main':
>   prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x26): undefined reference to `obj' 
>   collect2:
>   error: ld returned 1 exit status

I am not familiar with assembly language code. I borrowed this from some body else's code. I am using gcc-4.9 and Centos 7 x64 bit server.

Comment: Your inline asm is broken in several ways (you need to pass address of obj as input operand to inline assembly, you move random contents of %eax to obj). It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: and what are you doing within __asm__.?

Comment: @GreenTree: He is trying to set up the `this` pointer by loading the address of the object into EAX.  That's fine - provided the call statement doesn't accidentally use EAX to calculate the target address.

Comment: @MartinBonner, eax on x64 for address storing.?

Comment: and int for address. @Abhijatya Singh, you should use std::uintptr_t.

Comment: @GreenTree: That's not going to work well :-).  The OP could be generating 32 bit code, even on x64 server (although that is *much* commoner on Windows platforms).

Comment: I was trying to verify that first 4/8-byte of object has the address of VTABLE. For that I am trying to replace "this" pointer to obj address. So that I can access VTABLE internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obj is a local variable, it has no linkage, no symbol.
just try to make your object global.

Comment: I made obj as global and recompiled again. But output is : n = 1076818912 Which should be n=10. What is going wrong.

Comment: try to cast vptr[0] to pointer to function, that accepts pointer to X. and then pass objects address directly.

Comment: as in yugrs answer.

Comment: compile ( with -S option ) simple example without asm, casting, etc. and see the output ( with .s extension ).

Comment: Still gives garbage output.

Comment: output means file.s.

Comment: The output expected is n=10, but its coming n = 1425658941, 14 87546523,.... After every compilation and execution it changes.

Comment: file.s is an asm source file.! it is not execution file.! just look into it and try to do exactly what your compiler did.

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of inline asm and do

```
((void (*)(void *)) vptr[0])(&obj);
```

Warning: I assume that you run on gcc Linux x86_64 as ABI details on other platforms will be different.

Comment: That certainly won't work on 32-bit Windows.  The `this` pointer is *not* passed as a normal argument (it is passed in the ECX register).  I don't know how linux handles this in x86 and x64 modes

Comment: My gut feeling is that it'll work on most platforms for which GCC is main compiler (e.g. Linux) because you have [Itanium ABI](https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html) there.

Comment: @MartinBonner I wonder if you could add __thiscall to function type to force MSVS to use sane calling convention.